# Do we need to write apex trigger separately in each Salesforce account that works on a custom domain

Tags: apex

Our company has created a custom domain for Salesforce login and I have written apex triggers to perform a certain action when an event occurs. But this apex trigger is specific to my Salesforce account. What if my colleagues want to use the same? Do I need to configure it manually in each and every account or is there a way to use it on a common platform? Does custom domain play any part in making it common for a company's users?

This question may sound naive but I tried looking out and could not find an answer. I am new to Salesforce so still have a lot to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presuming you're all in the same org, the triggers will run for all users. My Domain has no effect on this behavior.